# Non convex optimization

Tags: optimization

For $u$ a unit vector and $x_1\ldots,x_n$ a set of fixed points in  $R^d$,  consider $f(u)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\langle x_i,u\rangle_+}{\langle x_i,u\rangle_-}$, where $a_+$ and $a_-$ are the corresponding positive and negative parts of a real $a$. Is there a general way of finding $\sup_u f(u)$?

So far, for $d=2$ I've managed to solve the problem in terms of polar coordinates (the optimal comes in terms of the angles of the given points, as I expected). However, I'm not an expert in this subject, so I was wondering if there's a known general solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $f(\cdot)$ depends on $i$. Do you want the supremum for every points $x_i$ separately?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the sum sign before the quotient... But it is for all the points!

Comment: What is the positive or negative part of a real number? Is it just a and -a?